# Hibernate save sql to file

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, file

I'd like to serialize entity to SQL-query string and save it into .txt file to be able to write it into database later. I need the solution to work regardless of SQL dialect, so I'd like to use Hibernate.

Is it possible to do it with Hibernate? Could you give me a clue or tutorial how could I accomplish this?

Let's assume we have an Entity:

```
@Entity  
public class Project {
       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
       private Long id;
       private String name;

       //... setters, getters and constructor
}
```

And I'd like to serialize some entities to strings of SQL statements like the following:

```
INSERT INTO project (name)
VALUES ('SQL Convertion Project');
INSERT INTO project (name)
VALUES ('DB Migration');
INSERT INTO project (name)
VALUES ('Stackoverflow is cool');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. I hope that it will help somebody.

The code below gets the insert and update queries for entity Project using Hibernate entity persister. I could inject the query parameters and write queries to files if I need to.

1. Using Hibernate framework only:

> ```
> Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
> StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().
>         applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
> SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
> ```

```
ClassMetadata hibernateMetadata = sessionFactory.getClassMetadata("com.mypackage.Project ");
if (hibernateMetadata == null){
    return;
}

if (hibernateMetadata instanceof AbstractEntityPersister) {
    AbstractEntityPersister persister = (AbstractEntityPersister) hibernateMetadata;

    for (Method method : persister.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredMethods()) {
        if (method.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("getSQLInsertStrings")) {
            ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(method);
            Object insertQueries = ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(method, persister);

            for (String queryText : (String []) insertQueries) {
                System.out.println(queryText);
            }
        }

        if (method.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("getSQLUpdateStrings")) {
            ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(method);
            Object insertQueries = ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(method, persister);

            for (String queryText : (String []) insertQueries) {
                System.out.println(queryText);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2. Using Hibernate + Spring

> ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
>               "ApplicationContext.xml");

```
EntityManager em = ((EntityManagerFactory) ctx.getBean("entityManagerFactory")).createEntityManager();
try {
    Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);

    ClassMetadata hibernateMetadata = session.getSessionFactory().getClassMetadata("com.mypackage.Project");
    if (hibernateMetadata == null){
        return;
    }
    if (hibernateMetadata instanceof AbstractEntityPersister) {
        AbstractEntityPersister persister = (AbstractEntityPersister) hibernateMetadata;

        for (Method method : persister.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredMethods()) {
            if (method.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("getSQLInsertStrings")) {
                ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(method);
                Object insertQueries = ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(method, persister);

                for (String queryText : (String []) insertQueries) {
                    System.out.println(queryText);
                }
            }

            if (method.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("getSQLUpdateStrings")) {
                ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(method);
                Object insertQueries = ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(method, persister);

                for (String queryText : (String []) insertQueries) {
                    System.out.println(queryText);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
finally {
    if (em != null) {
        em.close();
    }
}
```